# How to push message to app with the use of GCM?

Tags: php, android, mysql, google-cloud-messaging

recently I would like to implement push message to all app user cilent. So I found a Google service gcm. Since there are so several ways to implement and usage of GCM. The actual implementation is:

```
Develop by:
HTTP mode / php + mysql

Usage:
send message (notification) to all app users
```

Here is the php code from online tutorial

```
<?php
define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "AIzaSyCJiVkatisdQ44rEM353PFGbia29mBVscA");
define("GOOGLE_GCM_URL", "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");

function send_gcm_notify($reg_id, $message) {

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids'  => array( $reg_id ),
        'data'              => array( "message" => $message ),
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, GOOGLE_GCM_URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Problem occurred: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
 }

$reg_id = "APA91bHuSGES.....nn5pWrrSz0dV63pg";
$msg = "Google Cloud Messaging working well";

send_gcm_notify($reg_id, $msg);
```

Are there any tutorial that suit my case and not deprecated? Thanks. I already got the API key and the google service account is ready.

Comment: if it helps: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: gcm.jar is depreciated , but thanks your help anyway

Comment: for the server side code i meant, my mistake though, i haven't checked the latest one for any change

Comment: Nevermind, I am quite confuse about whether it is necessary to register the cilent device? Can I simply send the data to all device installed my app? As I don't need to send to a particular cilent

Comment: every mobile on which your app is installed becomes a client , so yes registration is needed

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a php page where you can input the message that needs to be sent for all the users

message.php

```
html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h6>GCM</h6>
        <h3>MESSAGE</h3>
        <form action="notification.php" method="post">

            <textarea id="message" name="msg" rows="6" cols="41" autofocus="true"></textarea>
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" class="btn_class" value="Send"/>

        </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

design.css

```
div#container{
position:absolute;
width:400px;
height:350px;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin-top:-225px;
margin-left:-200px;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

#message{
margin-left:25px;
}

.btn_class{
color:blue;
margin-left:170px;
}

h6{
text-align:center;
font-family:sans-serif;
font-size:20px;
}

h3{
margin-left:30px;
font-family:sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
}
```

Step 2: create notification.php file that upon receiving the message will send it to all the users using your api key and reg ids

notification.php

```
<?php

    $message=$_POST["msg"];
            ........
            // construct sql query for database access

            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

                   $registrationIDs[] = $row["gcm_regid"]; // store all reg ids from the column "gcm_regid" in the array
            }

            $fields = array(
                   'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
                   'data' => array( "message" => $message ),
             );
?>
```

The rest of the code is same as yours